# How to use GPU in pytorch?

Tags: python, installation, gpu, pytorch, conda

I tried following steps at: https://pytorch.org/get-started/locally/

First I created a conda environment as:

```
conda create -n facenet37_2 python=3.7
```

Then on above site I selected:

```
PyTorch Build: Stable (1.4)
OS: Linux (I am using Ubuntu 18.04)
Package: conda
Language: python
CUDA: 10.1
```

and it asked me to run following command:

```
conda install pytorch torchvision cudatoolkit=10.1 -c pytorch
```

But after that when I opened python and typed:

```
import torch
torch.cuda.is_available()
```

I get False

I have GeForce GT 630M (computeCapability: 2.1). But it is not getting detected. Why? Is it too old and no longer supported? How can I fix the issue?

Edit: Why did I get a negative vote?

Comment: Did you install the NVIDIA CUDA toolkit?

Comment: It's too old, you need a new GPU

Comment: No I didn't installed CUDA toolkit. I thought that will be taken care of. Do I have to ?

Comment: if installing from pip or conda then cuda and cudnn binaries are included. It won't even look at your system cuda installation. This isn't true if you build from source.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The GeForce GT 630M has compute capability 2.1 and therefore only supports up to CUDA 8.

- PyTorch **binaries** dropped support for compute capability <= 5.0 in [PyTorch 0.3.1](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/releases/tag/v0.3.1). It's not clear to me if compute capability 2.1 was ever included in the binaries.
- The PyTorch codebase dropped CUDA 8 support in [PyTorch 1.1.0](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/releases/tag/v1.1.0).

Due to the second point there's no way short of changing the PyTorch codebase to make your GPU work with the latest version. Your options are:

- Install PyTorch without GPU support.
- Try compiling PyTorch < 1.1.0 from source ([instructions](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/blob/v1.0.1/README.md#installation)). Make sure to checkout the v1.0.1 tag. This will produce a binary with support for your compute capability.
- If acceptable you could try installing a really old version: PyTorch < 0.3.1 using conda or a wheel and see if that works. It may have compute capability 2.1 support though I can't verify this. See [pytorch.org](https://pytorch.org/get-started/previous-versions/) for information. Though it looks like the link to https://download.pytorch.org/whl/cu80/torch_stable.html is broken.

Comment: For a detailed way of how to install pytorch with cuda support from source, see https://superuser.com/questions/1596115/how-to-install-pytorch-with-cuda-enabled-for-a-deprecated-cuda-cc-3-5-of-an-old.

Answer (score 1):

Your GPU architecture is Fermi. Last `CUDA` version with support for Fermi is `8.0` and you have installed `10.1`

The possible solution might be to install older `CUDA` and `PyTorch` version.

```sh
conda install pytorch==1.0.0 torchvision==0.2.1 cuda80 -c pytorch
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion... Sadly it didn't worked :-(

Comment: pytorch does not depend on the system cuda toolkit. If your card is not supported by the official "install code builder" at https://pytorch.org/get-started/locally/, you need to install from source, as @jodag says. See the Windows example [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1596115/how-to-install-pytorch-with-cuda-enabled-for-a-deprecated-cuda-cc-3-5-of-an-old).